# 'for' loop with dynamic array size

Tags: bash

I have an array that gets elements added to it when it calls the function findVar. The problem seems to be on the for loop that does not update the number of elements once started running.

When I do echo at the end of the for loop I get the correct number of elements and the last element but it seems not to be checking on the for conditions once started.

```
for var in "${tempV[@]}"
do
    num_words=${#tempV[@]}
    let i=i+1
    if ! [ $i -gt $num_words ]
    then
        findVar $objBKP $var
    fi
done
```

Comment: Does it have to be `bash`? Because at this point, I'd be thinking of using `perl`.

Comment: yeah, only bash. It can be a while loop though, not for loop necessary

Comment: BTW, consider getting in the habit of using http://shellcheck.net/; you've got bugs here related to missing quotes it would catch.

Comment: also, since you're relying on modern features such as arrays, there's no point to using antique syntax like `let` or `[ ]` for compatibility support. Even if you wanted to iterate by index for some strange reason [and didn't want to use `for i in "${!tempV[@]}"`, which is the approach robust against sparse arrays], you could use `for ((i=0; i<${#tempV[@]}; i++)); do`.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt is looping over every original element in the array and then ensuring that you haven't looped more times than that and calling your function.

That doesn't work because the original expansion of `tempV` happens once and so the added entries are never seen. But that also doesn't make sense since, by definition, if you are looping over the elements of the array you can't loop more times then there *are* elements in the array.

What you want to be doing (assuming a non-sparse, integer-indexed array that is **only** appended to) is looping numerically and checking that you haven't exceeded the array size as the loop condition.

Something like this (untested):

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt "${#tempV[@]}" ]; do
    var=${tempV[i]}
    findVar "$objBKP" "$var"
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `$i` for anything other than an iteration counter. It's completely unnecessary in your posted example. Instead, just iterate over the contents of the variable expansion. For example:

```
for var in "${tempV[@]}"; do
    findVar "$objBKP" "$var"
done
```

Comment: This doesn't help. The initial expansion only happens once so the new elements never get looped over.

Comment: @EtanReisner You're assuming *tempV* is an array that needs to be addressed by index. That's not mentioned anywhere by the OP, and is based on information not in evidence. If you want to base your answer on an alternate interpretation of the question, great! Otherwise, the comment is just bike-shedding. Either way, good luck!

Comment: I do (but that's a caveat I list in my answer and not the problem with your answer). The problem with your answer is that the entries *added to* `tempV` by the call to `findVar` will *never* be looped over as the expansion of `tempV` in the loop statement happens *before* those entries are added. Try `a=(1 2 3); for i in "${a[@]}"; do a+=("$i$i"); echo "Looping over $i"; done; declare -p a` and see what values you get in the loop and what values `a` ends up containing.